# Field collection translation structure: entity translation vs. node-type translation

Tags: 7, entities

I have a site with field collections and the entity_translation module that saves field collections after the following format:

When I save a new translation via the edit page, Drupal adds a new parent field collection row in field_data_field_parent_fc (en, en-gb, en-au). Each parent field collection points to a different text field (en -> 100, en-gb -> 101, en-au -> 102, etc.)

This is want I want to happen. There should be one row in field_data_field_parent_fc, containing language und, which points to a single text field (100). Then in the text field table, there should be a translation for en, en-gb, and en-au.

What I want is something akin to entity translation as opposed to node translation. Is there a setting for this, within the entity_translation module or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that while I had field collections enabled in /admin/config/regional/entity_translation, the language must be set to "Language neutral" for field collections. This creates a single "und" row, and the child text fields can have their own entries for language.

Also, make sure the "Field Translation" setting is disabled for field collections under /admin/structure/types/manage/{your_content_type}/fields/{your field collection field}. This way, the field collections won't be translated, but the underlying text fields will be.

Comment: What versions of core, field_collection and entity_translation are you using? I have the exact configuration describe in your answer but viewing the node does not work correctly (although the edit forms work fine). Because `field_myfc` is not a translated field it gets loaded as 'und', causing all child fields to "lose" the correct language that the node is being displayed as